# MySql replace what's after the last /

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to replace text after the last `/` in the path column, with text from the name column. The number of `/` in the path column are not fixed, but In every case, I'll need to replace only the text after the last `/`

What is the correct way to do this? I not very familiar with thing like these, and was trying something ridiculous that cleared all data:

```
UPDATE paths
    SET path = SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,'/', 1);
    select * from paths;
```

**Current Data**

```
"name"      "path"
"microsoft" "/us/software/mscorporation"
```

**Expected results**

```
"name"      "path" 
"microsoft" "/us/software/microsoft" 
//replace what's after the last `/` with what's in name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just wanted to improve vooD's answer.

```
UPDATE paths SET path = REPLACE(path, SUBSTRING_INDEX(path, '/', -1), name);
```

my rep isn't enough to comment :P

EDIT : query's above have a bug, example

```
us/system/driver/system

'path will become us/microsoft/driver/microsoft if name's value is microsoft
```

so, this should the right query :

```
UPDATE paths SET path = CONCAT(LEFT(path, CHAR_LENGTH(path) - CHAR_LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(path, '/', -1))),name)
```

Answer (score 1):

To select the substring after last `/` you can do:

```
select substring_index('/us/software/microsoft', '/', -1);
+--------------------------------------------------+
| substring_index('/us/software/microsoft','/',-1) |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| microsoft                                        |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

You **UPDATE** query can be:

```
UPDATE paths SET path = SUBSTRING(path, 1, LENGTH(path) - LOCATE('/', REVERSE(path)) )
  substring_index(name, '/', -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. It will replace everything after the last `/` with `microsoft`

```
UPDATE path SET path = REPLACE(path, SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '/', -1), 'microsoft');
```